# DOCX Portrait Images are not aligned with table cell

Tags: c#, docx, portrait

I am new to Docx, and it is really very handy, Thanks DOCX for this development. I have tried using DOCX with photos captured through mobile phone. The photos are portrait and some are landscape.

I do have a word template that I am loading when i run my app. while inserting photos into a tables, the photos does not look correctly placed ("Over Lapped").

[Example of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd5gW.png)

Please have a look on the code in this repo you may test it to see the results. I have also uploaded the used images to the repo. any thoughts?

https://github.com/mostafa901/Testing-Nova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after digging a lot, I said I should post my findings may be it come to be useful to someone. I discovered it is not a mistake in the code, but the template file used is of an old office version.
Thanks.